# hide this toolstrip down from another form load c# windows application

Tags: c#, winforms

Form2:
tolstrip menu dropdown create on intialize component on form 2.I tried to hide this toolstrip from form 1 load function but it won't work .

```
 this.mHelp.DropDownItems.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[2]
      {
        (ToolStripItem) this.contentsToolStripMenuItem,
        (ToolStripItem) this.apProposToolStripMenuItem
      });
      this.mHelp.Name = "mHelp";
      this.mHelp.Size = new Size(44, 20);
      this.mHelp.Text = "Help";
      this.contentsToolStripMenuItem.Name = "contentsToolStripMenuItem";
      this.contentsToolStripMenuItem.Size = new Size(122, 22);
      this.contentsToolStripMenuItem.Text = "Contents";
      this.contentsToolStripMenuItem.Click += new EventHandler(this.contentsToolStripMenuItem_Click);
      this.apProposToolStripMenuItem.Image = (Image) componentResourceManager.GetObject("apProposToolStripMenuItem.Image");
      this.apProposToolStripMenuItem.Name = "apProposToolStripMenuItem";
      this.apProposToolStripMenuItem.Size = new Size(122, 22);
      this.apProposToolStripMenuItem.Text = "About";
      this.apProposToolStripMenuItem.Click += new EventHandler(this.apProposToolStripMenuItem_Click);
this.Load += new EventHandler(this.DocumentSpace_Load);
```

Form1 :

```
 private void Home_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (about.Text == "About")
            {
                ((Button)about.Controls["button1"]).Text = "test_Button";
                ((Label)about.Controls["label3"]).Text = "test";
            }

            this.Show();
            this.Activate();
            this.SetFormName();

        }
```

Help me to sort out from this.

Comment: Can you show us the form1 load method?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking and the code also doesn't share useful information. Please describe more about the requirement and tell what the problem is.

Comment: @Cid edited with form1